# Is delete necessary when returning array from function

Tags: c++, c++17

When an array is created on the heap inside a function is it necessary to delete the array in the main function? Consider, this program:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int * return_array() {
    int* my_array = new int[10];
    my_array[0] = 10;
    return my_array;
}

int main()
{
    int * returned_array = return_array();
    cout << returned_array[0];
    delete[] returned_array;
    return 0;
}
```

This line: `int* my_array = new int[10];` is it necessary to delete in the main program? I find that doing this every time will hard to maintain and get right.

Comment: It is necessary. Use vectors instead. And forget about evil C arrays.

Comment: Yes, this is hard to maintain. That's why people haven't been using C++ like this for nearly a decade now.

Comment: Allocation → free/delete

Comment: You allocate it with `new` then you *own* and are responsible for releasing it unless you can give that responsibility to some other part of your code, in which case that code must release it.

Comment: Relevant read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/655206 , Numerous links to further reading: https://stackoverflow.com/a/716360

Answer (score 5):

Yes, in the code that you wrote, a call to `delete[]` is necessary after each call to `return_array()` because it is allocating new memory on the heap, which is not automatically reclaimed. Unlike Java and other higher level languages, C++ does not have a garbage collector. Failure to call `delete[]` will lead to memory leaks and an ever growing heap size.

As indicated by @Ron in the comments, a viable alternative is to use an `std::vector<int>` (if the array will never need to grow, then see also `std::array`). While the vector will internally use heap allocations, it also manages them automatically for you so that when they go out of scope their memory is automatically reclaimed.

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> return_vector() {
    std::vector<int> my_vector(10);
    my_array[0] = 10;
    return my_array;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> returned_vector = return_vector();
    std::cout << returned_vector[0];
    return 0; // vector internal memory is reclaimed
}
```

Comment: Re. the last paragraph, the compiler may decide to elide the copy completely. If not, then it is may use move semantics. The criteria for allowing move semantics are less restrictive than for copy elision, and, unlike copy elision, moving if the conditions are right is not optional.

Comment: @juanchopanza I wasn't aware that the compiler preferred move over copy. That's good to know!

Comment: Last paragraph is now wrong. Copy elision pre-dates C++11.

Comment: arg.... I'm just dropping the last paragraph because I apparently don't understand elision. It isn't terribly relevant to the question anyway. Reading up on it at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision

Comment: @juanchopanza Is the relevant elision above NVRO (named value return optimization)? There is neither a move nor a copy, but rather the vector `my_vector` inside `return_vector()` is allocated at the address of `returned_vector`? (e.g. "When that local object is constructed, it is constructed directly in the storage where the function's return value would otherwise be moved or copied to." from the above linked cppreference.com copy_elision article)

Comment: Partially, What is missing is the conditions for NRVO to be viable, and how those relate to a local object returned from a function being treated as an rvalue such that it may be moved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174094/discussion-between-nathan-and-juanchopanza).

Comment: @juanchopanza What are the missing conditions for NRVO to be viable in the example showed in this answer? The OP also tagged their question as C++17.

Answer (score 2):

Any object created on the free store with `new` has to be cleaned up by `delete`. Otherwise, you'll have a memory leak as once your method returns the memory isn't deallocated.