# Does the destructor of an object allocated dynamically (on heap) will be called automatically in return function?

Tags: c++

Maybe the question is basic but I didn't found answer for that.

I will give the some examples (when Object has destructor), and I will glad to understand what happens in each one:

1)

```
int f (){
  Object *p=new Object();
  int something=5;
  return something;
}
```

I think it would not call the destructor, but someone told me that if the function has return then the destructor will be called.

2)

```
Object & f (){
  Object *p=new Object();
  return *p;
}
```

How about now? is it connected to the object instance we return?

if 1) is not calling detractor please confirm that 3) is not calling the destructor (I still think it will not, but confirming)

3)

```
int f (){
  for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
     Object *p=new Object();
  }
  int something=5;
  return something;
}
```

If 1) is calling the destructor:  if 3) was void function, does the destructor
will be called (I again think not).

Comment: Whoever told you that, was mistaken. When something is constructed by a `new`, it only gets destroyed by a `delete`. No exceptions.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716353/must-new-always-be-followed-by-delete

Comment: Try this class and see when destructor is called:
```
class Object {
public:
  Object() = default;
  ~Object() {
    std::cout << "Object destroyed!\n";
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case #1, the destructor is NOT called, because the object exists in **dynamic** (heap) memory, so it will not be destructed until `delete` is called on it.  Every `new` needs a matching `delete`.

The destructor WOULD be called if the object were created in **automatic** (stack) memory instead, eg:

```
int f() {
    Object p; // <-- no 'new'
    int something=5;
    return something;
} // <-- ~Object() is called here
```

In case #2, the destructor of the object pointed to by `p` is NOT called, and the `return` statement is returning a **reference** to the same object that exists in dynamic memory.

If the function returned an `Object` **by value** instead of **by reference**, then the `return` statement would make a *copy*, and the copy WOULD be destructed (but not the original!) when the caller is done using the returned object, eg:

```
Object f() {
    Object *p=new Object();
    return *p; // <-- copy made here
}

f(); // <-- ~Object() for the return value
     // is called when the ';' is reached
```

In case #3, again the objects being created in dynamic memory are NOT destructed automatically upon return.

In all three cases, you can use `std::unique_ptr` to provide automatic memory management of dynamic objects, eg:

```
int f() {
  std::unique_ptr<Object> p(new Object);
  int something=5;
  return something;
} // <-- ~unique_ptr() is called here
```

```
std::unique_ptr<Object> f() {
  std::unique_ptr<Object> p(new Object);
  return std::move(p);
} // <-- ~unique_ptr() for p is called here

f(); // <-- ~unique_ptr() for the return value
     // is called when the ';' is reached
```

```
int f() {
  for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
     std::unique_ptr<Object> p(new Object);
  } // <-- ~unique_ptr() is called here
  int something=5;
  return something;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely not. C++ is not *garbage-collected* like Java.

*Every* `new` has to be balanced with a `delete`, and you need to pass the pointer you get back from `new` to that call to `delete`. (More formally that pointer has to be the same type too, or polymorphically related).

Fortunately, C++ does provide *smart pointer* classes like `std::unique_ptr` that wrap the `delete` call in its *destructor*.