# does this C++ function produce a memory leak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

If, in a function, I have the following code:

someClass *x = new object();
x = nullptr;

is this a memory leak?  Or, is the memory reallocated due to its local scope?

Thanks!

Not sure how to test this on my own.

Comment: Yes, this is explained in any [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). See also [Must new always be followed by delete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716353/must-new-always-be-followed-by-delete)

Comment: Whatever is `new`ed, must be `delete`d.

Comment: Note that this is not just a memory leak. Much worse things may generally happen because you are not properly destructing the constructed object.

Comment: That was what I thought, but I was having second thoughts if it happened in a function and wanted to be clear.  Thank you!

Comment: just about everything in C++ happens "in a function"

Comment: @DanielLangr, is that really true?  The code is simply not destructing the object...there is no improper destruction going on.

Comment: Classic memory leak in a nutshell.

Comment: @MarkB There are many things that may go wrong when skipping destructor call. For instance, you may have buffered data in memory that won't be written into a file and you will end up with corrupted file content.

Comment: This all makes sense, I just had a brain cramp and a moment of doubt regarding the scope, and thought that there was dedicated memory space for functions that would all be marked for reallocation once a function goes out of scope.  In this case, that applies to x, and not the new object, I presume.

Comment: @MarkB what if the class allocates resources, such as memory, file handles, sockets or whatever. not calling the destructor via delete leaks all those

Comment: @zbrusko yes if you said Object x; the thing would be created on the stack, and the destructor would be called for you when the function exits.

Comment: @zbrusko Pointers don't have destructors, so when they go out of scope **nothing happens**,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a memory leak. It is about the clearest example as one can get.